# C# Create new DateTime

Tags: c#

I have a variable date in C# that I create using

```
var date = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01)
```

The result of the date is 01/01/2000 -> this is the month/date/year

I want the result is in format date/month/year

I know I can format this one.. But is there another way around that date will automatically in format date/month/year without manually format the date?

Comment: Dates are numeric values. They don't have a *format*. You format for ease in reading for people. `date` doesn't contain any textual content and has no format.

Comment: So you all means it's default value of the date in month/date/year format.. To be changed to date/month/year I must formated the date variable manually?

Comment: @gill23, system default date format depends on language setting of your OS. if you have selected British English, it will format to 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

Comment: @gill23 - No, there is no default format. `DateTime` variables are just numbers - no format at all - and it's only when you try to display it that the framework applies a format. Normally it uses the default culture settings, but you can manually override and use whatever format you want. But the underlying `DateTime` does not have a format.

Comment: @gill23 - From your code, `new DateTime(2000, 01, 01)`, the underlying value for that `DateTime` is `630822816000000000`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .net Date formats are based on your machine localization. So you have two options.

1) change your machine language and culture settings.

2) change threads CultureInfo to render date in correct formate.

For more information see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yep I know this method, but bug will appear because my machine and the client machine have different settings.. I just wanna know from the code perspective. But thanks for your comment

Comment: Well, you can play tricks. Find client's culture and set accordingly. If you have asp.net app, you can easily do that.

Comment: @gill23 - What do you mean by "bug"?

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the big misunderstanding from the question: DateTime doesn't have an intrinsic format. It's just a number.

Comment: @mason, good question. Instead of posting lengthy text here, I gave a reference to more authentic resource.

Comment: @Saleem - You shouldn't put external links in answers unless they support the content already contained in the answer. SO has the view that external links may break and shouldn't therefore be relied on.

Comment: Well, it's link to MSDN and I don't think it's ever going to be changed. It also support what I suggested in my answer. I see your solution down there is no different than what I proposed.

Comment: @Saleem His answer is greatly superior to yours because it actually addresses the misunderstanding from the question, yours does not. A link to MSDN is not sufficient.

Answer (score 10):

If you look in the source code for the .NET framework for the `DateTime` type you'll find this line:

```
private ulong dateData;
```

That's how the `DateTime` is stored. There is no format.

From your code, `new DateTime(2000, 01, 01)`, the underlying value for that `DateTime` is `630822816000000000`.

But, when you go to display a date it would be exceedingly unhelpful if `.ToString()` produced `630822816000000000` instead of something like `01/01/2000`.

So, still in the source, you'll find this override:

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return DateTimeFormat.Format(this, (string) null, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}
```

Effectively, the `.ToString()` method uses the current culture's info for formatting dates.

You can always do this to ensure you get consistent results:

```
var date = new DateTime(2000, 4, 16);

var us = date.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
var au = date.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-au"));
```

This results in the following formats respectively:

```
4/16/2000 12:00:00 AM
16/04/2000 12:00:00 AM
```